# Python `filter.sobel()` input

Tags: python

Trying to use the `filter.sobel()` function in Python.

```
from PIL import Image
from skimage import data, io, filter
#...

image = Image.open('ME.jpg')
#right below is what it would normally be. I tried to substitute the code above for this
#image = data.coins()
edges = filter.sobel(image)
io.imshow(image)
io.show()
io.imshow(edges)
io.show()
```

o/p:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "edg.py", line 7, in <module>
    edges = filter.sobel(image)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/skimage/filter/edges.py", line 83, in sobel
    return np.sqrt(hsobel(image, mask)**2 + vsobel(image, mask)**2)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/skimage/filter/edges.py", line 114, in hsobel
    result = np.abs(convolve(image, HSOBEL_WEIGHTS))
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/ndimage/filt    ers.py", line 664, in convolve
    origin, True)
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/ndimage/filt    ers.py", line 498, in _correlate_or_convolve
    raise RuntimeError('filter weights array has incorrect shape.')
RuntimeError: filter weights array has incorrect shape.
```

How do I convert my image to an array like the one that is in `data.coins()`?

Comment: That depends, what's in `data.coins()`?

Comment: It's an array apparently. Probably an array of pixels intensities?

Comment: do I use `srcArray = numpy.asarray(src)`?

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use the image reader from scikit-image ? 
Or else, just use a black&white version to run the algorithm.
To do it, just pass the argument 'as_grey' to imread (I am making use of scikit-image):

```
image = skimage.io.imread(image_path,as_grey=True)
```

This reference may help you:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#imread